# Can I use FileHelpers to populate an existing class?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I'm trying load data from CSV files to default html dropdown lists. So, I want load the CSV in SelectListItem class. But, I cant find an option to make it, because FileHelpers need a "proxy" class with attributes like "DelimitedRecord", etc.

Obviously we cannot add attributes in a existing class, neither subclass "SelectListItem" to add the attributes.

There are then some way to tell FileHelpers that I want to use the specific SelectListItem class, and tell I need fill the "Text" and "Value" properties?

Answer (score 2):

You can make it in two steps.

First you read the CSV file with your FileHelpers library to a data structure of your choice, with the properties the same as your CSV file. As quoted from http://www.filehelpers.net/quickstart/:

> ### Mapping Class
>
> ```
> using FileHelpers;
>
> [DelimitedRecord(",")]
> public class Customer
> {
>   public int CustId;
>
>   public string Name;
>
>   public decimal Balance;
>
>   [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "dd-MM-yyyy")]
>   public DateTime AddedDate;
>
> }
> ```
>
> ### Create a FileHelperEngine for Read and Write
>
> ```
> var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Customer>();
>
> // To Read Use:
> var result = engine.ReadFile("FileIn.txt");
> [...]
> ```

Now you have a list if your data from the CSV file. Then you create `SelectListItem` objects with the data from the `Customer` objects (in this example).

A simple `Select()` LINQ call will do:

```
var items = result.Select(it => return new SelectItem {
    Text = whatever,
    Value = whatever
});
```